# Is the rootScope same or not the same if I open two identical angularjs app?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-rootscope

I developed a single page website with the AngularJS framework.My website will receive logs from other servers and render them on the page. When I open two identical pages of my app in the same browser, I can see that then rootScope (I may use too much rootScope to store my data) of the page that was opened later is updated, and the rootScope of the first opened page is no longer update. My question is, will the rootScope of the second open page overwrite the first page? If so, how do I guarantee to open two identical app, but Scope is independent?

Comment: How do you use $rootScope to store data, can you give an example, and by two identical pages, you mean in the same app?

Comment: Rootscopes should be independent of each other. Could it be that your backend can handle only one client+